# Deploying and running a Python Flask/Socketio webapp

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, frontend

I recently found [this example](https://github.com/shanealynn/async_flask) about Flask and SocketIO, where some numbers are generated with a Python script, sent via Websocket to the frontend and are printed in real-time dynamically on a Web page.

I want to build a Webapp based on Flask/SocketIO and on this example, but since i am fairly new to Python, i had the following doubt:

Let's say i deploy that simple app somewhere where it runs 24/7, for example on Heroku. Will the app start working and printing numbers **only** when someone opens it on a browser, showing different numbers to each, or will it run for the whole time, showing the same thing to each one who opens it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experience with this library since I created small online auction app. Reading `application.py`, every time someone connects, for example opens his browser, it will render `index.html` and start thread if it's first connection. If there are users before, it will not start, because it's already running and it will emit random numbers to all users connected.

For first connection -> [permalink to code](https://github.com/shanealynn/async_flask/blob/653d76d4db1e1e3cc4277cbd8319de5a538537e9/application.py#L75)

For emiting random numbers every second (delay is 1) -> [permalink to code](https://github.com/shanealynn/async_flask/blob/653d76d4db1e1e3cc4277cbd8319de5a538537e9/application.py#L57)

I think if you deploy application like this to *heroku*, it will only start emitting numbers if someone opens his browser, it will not emit before.

Comment: Thanks! Isn't there a way to make it run 24/7?

Comment: You can run it on some hosting services (pythonanywhere.com offers free hosting for python apps, you just have to configure it). It will always be there, available to everyone 24/7, but when someone connects, it will start generating random numbers.  Btw, It's little hard to configure flask-socketio, be sure to read documentation on how to deplay those kind of applications...

Comment: The problem is that I have a Python script which receives data and counts this data. Let's say I run this script on a server and after 6 hours since it started running it counted until 2 millions and sends this 2 million data to the front end. If a random person opens my front-end why doesn't he see "2M" but instead it will start from 0 again?

Comment: RandomThread generates random numbers in range 0 to 10 and it rounds them on 3 decimal places, every second. For anyone who connects, it will see random number. On the other hand, you can store some values in variable, and as long as server is running (the host), you data will be saved, they won't restart or delete until you stop a server. You can count number of connections or something... If you stop a server, it will reset to default. If you want to permanently store data, you can save it in file or database.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I helped you. Carry on :)